# Proof-Check: Beta-distribution sample generation through variable transformation

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, self-learning, transformation, monte-carlo

**Purpose of this thread:** I want your feedback on my proof for the following problem and correct it where necessary.

**Problem:** For $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta > 0$, consider the following accept–reject algorithm:

1. Generate $U_1$ and $U_2$ iid uniform$(0,1)$ random variables. Set $V_1 = U_1^{1/\alpha}$ and $V_2 =U_2^{1/\beta}$.
2. Set $W = V_1 + V_2$. If $W \leq 1$, set $X = V_1/W$; else go to step 1.
3. Deliver X.

Show that X has a beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

**Related threads:** This question as a complete proof [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/80959/183497).

**My attempt:** Using the so called [probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform#Statement), we get that the cdf of $V_1$ and $V_2$ are $F_{V_1}(v_1) = v_1^\alpha$ and $F_{V_2}(v_2) = v_2^\beta$. We want
$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
F_X(x) &= P(X \leq x) &= P\left(V_1/(V_1+V2 \leq x) \bigr\rvert V_1 + V_2 \leq 1 \right) \\
&&= \cfrac{P \left( \frac{V_1}{V_1+V_2} \leq x, V_1+V_2 \leq 1 \right)}{P\left( V_1 + V_2 \leq 1\right)} \\
\end{array}
$$

One approach is to simply manage with the joint pdf of $V_1$ and $V_2$ as was done [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/80959/183497). My approach was to define certain relevant transformations which could directly lead us to the exact expression for the cdf of the beta distribution.

Consider the transformations $Y = V_1/(V_1+V_2)$ and the given $W = V_1+V_2$. Then we have $V_1 = YW$ and $V_2 = W-YW$, the Jacobian would be $W$ and so the joint pdf ends up being
\begin{array}{ll}
f_{Y,W}(y,w) &= \alpha(yw)^{\alpha-1}\beta(w-yw)^{\beta-1} \times w \\
&= \alpha \beta w^{\alpha + \beta -1} y^{\alpha -1 }(1-y)^{\beta - 1}
\end{array}

**Check if joint pdf integrates to $1$:**

As $v_1$ and $v_2$ change from $0$ to $1$ ($0$ and $1$ are not a part of the support as question specifically mentions "uniform$(0,1)$"), the transformed variable $y$ changes from $0$ to $1$ while $w$ changes from $0$ to $2$. However, as $v_1 < 1$, $yw < 1$. Also, $v_2 < 1$ implies $w-yw < 1$ which leads to additional constraints on the integration limits as $(w-1)/w < y < 1/w$ (this is valid as $0 < w < 2$).

These constraints when expressed for $w$ in terms of $y$ end up being

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
0 < w < \frac{1}{1-y} & \text{, if } 0 < y < 1/2 \text{,} \\
0 < w < \frac{1}{y} & \text{, if } 1/2 < y < 1 \text{.}
\end{array}
$$

The above defines the region of integration for the pdf which needs to integrate to unity if derived correctly. With that, we need to show that
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \int_{0}^{1/(1-y)} f_{Y,W}(y,w) dw dy + \int_{1/2}^{1} \int_{0}^{1/y} f_{Y,W}(y,w) dw dy = 1.
$$

Now

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\int_0^{1/2} \int_{0}^{1/(1-y)} \alpha \beta w^{\alpha + \beta -1} y^{\alpha -1 }(1-y)^{\beta - 1} dw dy + \int_{1/2}^{1} \int_{0}^{1/y} \alpha \beta w^{\alpha + \beta -1} y^{\alpha -1 }(1-y)^{\beta - 1} \\
=  \frac{\alpha \beta}{\alpha + \beta} \left\{ \int_0^{1/2} \frac{y^{\alpha -1 }}{(1-y)^{\alpha + 1}} dy + \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{(1-y)^{\beta - 1}}{y^{\beta +1 }} dy \right\}\\
= \frac{\alpha \beta}{\alpha + \beta} \left\{ \frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta} \right\} \\
=1.
\end{array}
$$

This establishes that (at least :)) the derived joint pdf is valid!

**Derivation of $F_X(x):$**

Now that we have established that the joint pdf is valid, we evaluate the numerator and the denominator of the expression for $F_X(x)$. As the conditional probability involves the region where $w \leq 1$, we just have to integrate the joint pdf in the region $0 < y < 1$ and
$0 < w \leq 1$.

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
P \left( \frac{V_1}{V_1+V_2} \leq x, V_1+V_2 \leq 1 \right) &= P \left( Y \leq x, W \leq 1 \right)\\
&= \int_0^{x} \int_{0}^{1} \alpha \beta w^{\alpha + \beta -1} y^{\alpha -1 }(1-y)^{\beta - 1} dw dy \\
&= \frac{\alpha \beta}{\alpha + \beta} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)} I(x,\alpha,\beta)
\end{array}
$$

where $I(x,\alpha,\beta)$ is the [incomplete beta function which is the standard beta distribution cdf according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function). Next, the denominator in the expression for $F_X(x)$ is

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
P \left( V_1+V_2 \leq 1 \right) &= P \left( W \leq 1 \right)\\
&= \int_0^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \alpha \beta w^{\alpha + \beta -1} y^{\alpha -1 }(1-y)^{\beta - 1} dw dy \\
&= \frac{\alpha \beta}{\alpha + \beta} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}
\end{array}
$$

and thus we can finally conclude that $F_X(x) = I(x,\alpha,\beta)$.

Please let me know if there are any errors in the proof.

Comment: Somebody voted to close this question, and has downvoted my post. I'd appreciate it if that person can please comment and mention the reason for that action.

Comment: I don't get the heavy lament about societal decay in the bounty description. Proof checking is inherently laborious, and there is no indication here that you know where your proof might be at fault. This makes it unlikely that people here will spend time on this question.

Comment: I did not not, at the time of throwing in the bounty, that they would make my "lament" public. I even raised a flag to remove it and they didn't. Also, if I knew where the proof might be wrong, then this question is not valid because I'd know where I am going wrong in this proof. I usually ask for a proof check when I don't know about mistakes I'd have made. This is an important result proposed by Kennedy and Gentle published in 1980. How I wish someone took the interest to check the proof for it's correctness.